# unable to convert json response from array to object using javascript & angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular

[![enter image description here][1]][1]i have a json response

i want it in the format of object like

i tried using the

```
Object.assign({},...data)
```

but im getting the result as 0,1,2,3 line by line

```
0: "["
1: "↵"
2: " "
3: " "
4: "{"
5: "↵"
6: " "
7: " "
8: " "
9: " "
10: """
```

i am getting data like that from server as a  array and now i convert as object so that i can use it for further methods

Comment: `data = data[0]`

Comment: `what if i have more that on object of data` if your array has more than one element, how do you want the single object you seem to be looking for to look like? Please clarify what you actual goal is here. Tell us how you're planning to use the server response.

Comment: @ChrisG check comment below in my answer

Comment: @PardeepJain Why? Nothing below your answer makes sense or is constructive. $100 this is an XY problem and the solution is very simple and obvious once we know what the goal is.

Comment: can you explain your scenario, why you want to get object from array. may be we find or provide a better solution after knowing about your scenario rather than asking questions like this.

Comment: @ChrisG so any feasible solution why i wan to convert from array to object bcoz i want to object  properties like   a['d']

Comment: @FarhatZaman  based on the object i want to consume the object properties and send it to another object

Comment: @Dexter If you want help, please focus. "Convert from array to object" is a nonsensical concept if you have an array of similar objects to begin with. Take a step back and tell us about the big picture. And please, read this: [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Dexter can you provide a rough example?

Comment: @ChrisG could u please check the update question with image im getting data like that as array and for further use it has to be object

Comment: @Dexter I seriously don't know what else I have to do to get you to jump off this train to nowhere and start heading in the right direction. I've told you multiple times that your approach is nonsense, and in order to help you, we need to know what your **ACTUAL GOAL** is. `for further use it has to be object` that is UTTER NONSENSE. No offense. Please just tell me what you are trying to do, or I'll be flagging this as extremely low quality and move on.

Comment: @ChrisG   i mentioned it right  i consumed a array which came in resp body and that i want to convert it as object so that   i can get access to the object properties like   a[''date']  like that

Comment: From the console image it looks like you have a JSON string. Which means in order to access anything, you have to parse it first: `var data = JSON.parse(response);` Only then can you do something like `console.log(data[0].mimetype)`

Comment: @ChrisG i did the json.parse here what i did  let a = JSON.stringify(data);
       let b = JSON.parse(a);
       let c = b._body;
    
       console.log(b._body);
       let d = Object.assign({},...c);

Comment: @ChrisG here im getting enter symbols & whitepsace

Comment: Please put the code you're using *in the question*. The code you have suggests that all you need is `let array = data._body; let firstObject = data[0];` You're using angular, and grabbing JSON and parsing it into an object is a solved problem. You shouldn't have to do it yourself. And stringifying an object only to then parse the string is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign your array's first index to some variable like below -

```
let newObj = data[0]
```

Comment: what if i have more that on object of data

Comment: @Dexter same for others, FYI don't mix an array of objects with objects of the array. But this is not a recommended way ever

Comment: i am getting actually data like this when i use object.assign                                0: "["
1: "↵"
2: " "
3: " "
4: "{"
5: "↵"
6: " "
7: " "
8: " "
9: " "
10: """

Comment: yes because it will iterate over each element of array and trying to convert it into key value pair, For example `Object.assign({}, ['a','b','c']);` will clear you everything

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Object.assign({},...data)`.

You can simply get the desired result by calling `data[0]`.

If you want to check then use `console.log(data[0]);`.